# ¿como generar un archivo csv con datos de una imagen.dcm desde python?

Tags: python

Me gustaría que me ayudaran si es posible.
Quiero generar un archivo.csv con datos dicom desde Python, este es el código que he implementado: Lo que he hecho es abrir la carpeta que contiene las imágenes.dcm y obtener solo el nombre que yo deseo introducir en el archivo csv. En este caso, el nombre lo guardo en una variale llamada nombre guardar y posteriormente lo introduzco en el fichero.csv
El problema que tengo es que, al abrir el archivo csv, no se me guarda el nombre me sale vacio. Si alguien me pudiese ayudar estaría muy agradecid con ud

```
import glob
import pydicom
import csv

for file in glob.glob("C:/Users/desco/Desktop/ImagenesDICOM/*.dcm"):
ds = pydicom.dcmread(file)
name=ds.PatientName
nombre_gurdar=""
if (name=="Nombre 1"):
    nombre_gurdar=name
    print(nombre_gurdar)
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

writer.writeheader()
writer.writerow({'first_name': nombre_gurdar, 'last_name': 'Beans'})
print(nombre_gurdar)
```

Comment: Podrías añadir el código en vez de una image?

Comment: vale, ya he añadido el código y he quitado la imagen